# Substitute character at fixed index in a string

Tags: r

I want to substitute a character at a fixed location in a string

Example: `c("abcdefg", "123456")`

I need to change the fourth character ('d' & '4' in the example) to '0'.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substring` to extract the 4th character and assign it to '0'.

```
substring(v1, 4) <- '0'
```

Or we use `sub`,  capture the first three characters (`.{3}`), 5th character to end of string (`(.*)$`).  In the replacement, we use the first capture group (`\\1`) followed by 0 followed by the second capture group (`\\2`).

```
sub('(.{3}).(.*)$', '\\10\\2', v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c("abcdefg", "123456")
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that substring can be used to alter the original string.

Comment: @DavideRivola The abbreviate version `?substr` won't be able to do that if we don't specify the `stop` i.e. `substr(v1, 4,4) <- '0'`

Comment: kiss, `sub('^(.{3}).', '\\10', v1)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, that is more compact.